# Get filename and add to list

Tags: c#, winforms, file, search, filenames

I need to add the name of file to my list view which is .log type. I have something like this but it shows only path to that file. My code:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\...","*.log");

foreach (string file in files)
{
   listView1.Items.Add(file);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you can use either `Path.GetFileName` and `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\...","*.log");

foreach (string file in files)
{
   string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
   listView1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.log");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this probelm :

```
const string ExtExe = ".log";
const string MaskExe = "*" + ExtExe;

var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, MaskExe).Where(item => item.ToLower().EndsWith(ExtExe));
foreach(string file in files) 
{
    put your logic....
}
```